# Swift - Refresh View Controller after changing Tabbar's height

Tags: ios, swift, tabbar

I'm making an MP3 Player app. When a song is selected, a Player appears. When the Player is minimized, a mini player will be sticked on top of Tabbar so user can pause/play/next/prev anywhere. My custome Tabbar:

```
class CustomTabBar: UITabBar {
@IBInspectable var height: CGFloat = 0.0

override open func sizeThatFits(_ size: CGSize) -> CGSize {
    guard let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow else {
        return super.sizeThatFits(size)
    }
    var sizeThatFits = super.sizeThatFits(size)
    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
        sizeThatFits.height = height + window.safeAreaInsets.bottom
    } else {
        sizeThatFits.height = height
    }
    return sizeThatFits
}
```

Update Tabbar's height by: `customTabBar.height = 121` which is ok. But the problem is the displaying view controller won't refresh its Safe Area to fit new tabbar, and some bottom components are "hidden".

[image: Last cell stays behind Tabbar]

But after I switch to another tab and switch back, the problem is gone.

[image: After switching tabs]

So I guess that the view controller which is presenting doesn't get refreshed after tabbar's height changed. Please help me with a refresh solution or another way to archive "a mini player that can view from anywhere".

Big thanks!

Comment: hi, do you found your solutoin yet? im having the same issue as yours

Comment: unfortunately, I didn't. I had to fix tabbar's height